# $\text{Res}_{z=0}\frac{z^a}{z^b}$ for $b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^{+} \setminus \mathbb{N}$

Tags: residue-calculus, laurent-series

Given that $\frac{z^a}{z^b}$ for $b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^{+} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ has a pole of order $b$ at the origin, I chose to employ the derivative-limit formula.

$$\text{Res}_{z=0} \frac{z^a}{z^b} = \frac{1}{(b-1)!} lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^{b-1}}{dz^{b-1}} \left(z^b \frac{z^a}{z^b}\right)$$

I then assert that calculation of the residue is no more than evaluating this limit.
$$\frac{1}{(b-1)!} \text{lim}_{z \to 0} \frac{d^{b-1}}{dz^{b-1}} \left(z^a\right) = \frac{(a)(a-1)...(a+2-b)}{(b-1)!} \text{lim}_{z \to 0} z^{a+1-b} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} & a+1 > b \\ \infty  & \text{if} & b > a+1 \\ \frac{(a)(a-1)...(a+2-b)}{(b-1)!} & \text{if} & b=a+1 & \text{(impossible given that $a \in \mathbb{R}^+ \setminus \mathbb{N}$)} \end{cases}$$

When I had originally studied complex analysis, I had never encountered an infinite residue, so I believe that I have made a rather obvious mistake somewhere in my reasoning. If a residue were infinite, would that imply that the Laurent series for the function would not exist or diverge everywhere in an annular region around the origin?

Comment: If $a$ is not an integer, there is no way t9 make $\frac{z^a}{z^b}$ analytic near $0,$ so it is meaning to talk of a pole at $0,$ nor the residue at $0.$

Comment: In my previous comment “meaning” should be “meaningless.”

Comment: Do you have a source for this result? Surprisingly, it was not mentioned in my textbook. I assume that the Cauchy-Riemann equations would fail even for rational $a$, so ensuring the continuity of first partials would not even be necessary. Thank you again.

Comment: Just common knowledge. If $a=3/2,b=1,$ you can’t make $\sqrt z$ analytic near zero. More generally, this function can be written as $e^{(a-b)\ln z}$ but $\ln z$ always has a branch cut and can’t be made analytic in any punctured disk around $0.$

Comment: Thank you, I'll close the question. I had been examining a different problem, and my excitement led me to neglect reason. If you post your final comment as an answer, I'll accept it.